# C++ regex replace first match

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11

I tried to write a method which acts like Java's `Matcher::replaceFirst(String replacement)`. I know how to replace all matches in a `std::string`, with `std::regex_replace`, but how can I only replace the first match of a regex in a string?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::regex_replace` with an additional flag, `std::regex_constants::format_first_only`, to get the result you want.

Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `std::regex_replace` by specifying `format_first_only` as an argument to the flag parameter of `std::regex_replace()`.

Look here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_flag_type