# Replace nth regex match in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, regex-replace

I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518089/c-regex-replace-first-match) which only explains how to replace the first regex match. What about some n'th match?

Say I have a string and a regex like these:

```
std::string str  = "fast cast dust crust must last rust";
std::regex  expr = " .(a|u)st";
```

How can I replace, say, the third match with some other sequence? `std::regex_replace` allows to replace either all matches or the first one. I'm also thinking about `std::regex_iterator`, but still can't figure out how to apply it in this task. What are the most convenient ways to solve the problem?

Comment: Make a regex that first matches the first n-1 occurences followed by one extra occurence

Comment: It should be mentioned that there are a lot of solutions here on SO with regexps that are designed to specifically replace an Nth match. Like `^((?:.*?pattern){n-1}.*?)pattern` and replace with `$1` (backreference to Group 1). Does it sound sufficient for you? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/55j6tD/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it still requires messing around with the expression itself, which is what I'd like to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to come up with my own solution. I use `std::string::replace` taking a pair of iterators in the first `std::sub_match` from the advanced `std::sregex_iterator`:

```
std::string str = "fast cast dust crust must last rust";
std::regex expr{" .(a|u)st"};
std::sregex_iterator regex_it{str.cbegin(), str.cend(), expr};

std::advance(regex_it, 2);
str.replace(regex_it->cbegin()->first, regex_it->cbegin()->second, " lol");
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

One could add some extra iterator validations if they wish. I'll keep it brief.

The output is:

```
fast cast dust crust lol last rust
```

It's worth mentioning, however, that `std::regex_replace` returns a modified copy whereas the solution above changes the string in place. Also, one should be careful as the iterators in the `sub_match`es may become invalidated once the replacement has been completed.